# How to save ndarray or show anim?

Tags: python, python-3.9, tomography-reconstruction, tigre

I am using [TIGRE](https://github.com/cern/tigre/) (an open source toolbox for reconstruction provided by CERN). The original code was written for python 3.7 and is struggling to run correctly on 3.9.

This is the original code and the error it produces.

```
#%% Initialize
import tigre
import numpy as np
from tigre.utilities import sample_loader
from tigre.utilities import CTnoise
import tigre.algorithms as algs

#%% Geometry
geo = tigre.geometry_default(high_resolution=False)

#%% Load data and generate projections
# define angles
angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
# Load thorax phatom data
head = sample_loader.load_head_phantom(geo.nVoxel)
# generate projections
projections = tigre.Ax(head, geo, angles)
# add noise
noise_projections = CTnoise.add(projections, Poisson=1e5, Gaussian=np.array([0, 10]))

#%% Reconstruct image using OS-SART and FDK

# FDK
imgFDK = algs.fdk(noise_projections, geo, angles)
# OS-SART

niter = 50
imgOSSART = algs.ossart(noise_projections, geo, angles, niter)

imgOSSART.save

#%% Show the results
tigre.plotimg(np.concatenate([imgFDK, imgOSSART], axis=1), dim="z")
```

Error:

```
  File ~\TIGRE\Python\demos\d04_SimpleReconstruction.py:54 in <module>
    imgOSSART.save

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'
```

When I remove the `imgOSSART.save`, the program runs but returns an empty figure:

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py:889: UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you have outputted the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.
  warnings.warn(
```

Does anyone know a way to tackle this or to get python 3.7?

Comment: Well, getting Python 3.7 is easy with something like miniconda. Install Miniconda3 (if you don't already have it) and create an environment with `conda create --name py37env python==3.7`. Better yet, create a specific environment just for this project, with a name more specific to the project.

Comment: Where did this code come from? Did you write it yourself? Or did you copy paste it from somewhere? Double check that you have the most recent version of the source.

Comment: Happy to see someone use my tool :) Feel free to ask in the Github Issues/Discussion too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In numpy ndarrays are saved using the [`numpy.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) function. So, try something like this instead

```py
np.save('imgOSSART.npy', imgOSSART)
```

However, I don't think this solves the problem.

---

The code snippet seems to be from [here](https://github.com/CERN/TIGRE/blob/bde3d952bbc63586928dd5f29e4fa1be30aed573/Python/demos/d04_SimpleReconstruction.py), which does not include `np.save`.

To save the animation as a gif, you can try adding `savegif` parameter

```py
tigre.plotimg(
   np.concatenate([imgFDK, imgOSSART], axis=1), 
   dim="z", 
   savegif='filename.gif'
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been stuck on this for over a month. Saving as a gif was perfect.